# Multiple Callbacks in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I am trying to work out the correct behavior to string multiple callbacks together.

```
class Person

  move_head: ->
     head.animate({
        left: x,
     },{
        complete: @move_foot,
     });

  move_foot: ->
     foot.animate({
        left: x,
     },{
        complete: @move_arm,
     });

  move_arm: ->
     arm.animate({
        left: x,
     },{
        complete: something_else,
     });
```

Now the issue is, head animates fine which calls foot.  Foot also animates fine.  The problem is that when foot is done, it does not animate the arm.  I can't figure out what the problem could be.  I have a guess though that it might have to do with a scoping issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the fat arrow `=>`, to bind `this` to current context:

```
move_head: =>
  // ...
move_foot: =>
  // ...
move_arm: =>
  // ...
```

**UPDATE:** Here's a short explanation:

One of the biggest gotchas in javascript is `this`. In a method (such as your `move_head`), `this` is your instance of Person, if you call it as `new Person().move_head()`. But it doesn't have to be. For instance, if you call it using `new Person().move_head.call(null)`, `this` will be `null`.

But the biggest gotcha is that when you are inside a `function`, like a `complete` callback to a jQuery animate call, `this` is no longer bound to your object! It is probably bound to `window`, but not for certain. So what happens in your case is that you give jQuery a reference to `@move_foot` (or really, `this.move_foot`). This call seems to work, in that your animation completes. But when jQuery calls that function, it will no longer know that `this` is supposed to be your Person. So when you tell it to then go to `@move_arm`, it will look for a method `move_arm` on some other object (perhaps `window`).

A common way to solve this is to save a reference to `this` before you make the call, like `var self = this`, and then, inside the callback, refer to that bound variable `self` instead.

You could use this technique, there is nothing wrong with it. Something like:

```
move_head: ->
  self = this
  head.animate(..., complete: self.move_foot)
```

But CS does this (binding of `this`) for you, by giving you the fat arrow: `=>`.

The fat arrow says: "Everything inside this method referring to `this`, shall refer to this object."