# Anonymous function works as callback but defined function does not

Tags: coffeescript

I have a module that looks like this:

```
module.exports = AtomMarkdownLabels =
  # other stuff here

  file_changed_added: (file_path) =>
    fs.readFile file_path, 'utf-8', @process_yaml
    console.log 'file changed'

  process_yaml: (err, data) =>
    console.log "process_yaml is called"
```

I know `file_changed_added` is being called from some other function and I'm seeing the "file changed" output in the console, but `process_yaml` isn't if I change `file_changed_added` to

```
file_changed_added: (file_path) =>
    fs.readFile file_path, 'utf-8', (err, data) =>
      console.log "test"
    console.log 'file changed'
```

I see both "test" and "file changed" being called properly. What could be going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=>` has two slightly different purposes:

1. When defining a named function (`f = => ...`) or anonymous function `f(x, => ...)`), `=>` simply ensures that `@` inside the function is that same as `@` in the surrounding context.
2. When defining a method in a class:

   ```
   class C
     m: => ...
   ```

   `=>` ensures that `@` inside `m` will be the instance of `C`.

Both uses are creating a bound function but they're binding to different things.

You're using this structure:

```
obj =
  func: =>
    # ...
```

That's equivalent to this:

```
f = =>
  # ...
obj =
  func: f
```

because you're using a plain old object rather than a class. So what is `@` outside your `AtomMarkdownLabels` definition? `@` won't be anything useful and in particular, it won't be your `AtomMarkdownLabels` object and it won't have a `process_yaml` property so `@process_yaml` inside `file_changed_added` is going to be `undefined` or an error.

I'm not sure what specifically Atom wants you to return but a class should work, something like this:

```
# Use a class so that => does what you're expecting it to do
class AtomMarkdownLabels
  # other stuff here

  file_changed_added: (file_path) =>
    fs.readFile file_path, 'utf-8', @process_yaml
    console.log 'file changed'

  # you may or may not need => here
  process_yaml: (err, data) =>
    console.log "process_yaml is called"

# Export an instance of your class
module.exports = new AtomMarkdownLabels
```

If you want to or must use a plain object then you could bypass `@` completely and do it like this:

```
# Just plain old functions so define them that way
process_yaml = (err, data) ->
  console.log "process_yaml is called"

file_changed_added = (file_path) ->
  fs.readFile file_path, 'utf-8', process_yaml
  console.log 'file changed'

module.exports = AtomMarkdownLabels =
  # other stuff here

  file_changed_added: file_changed_added
```

or like this:

```
# Explicitly name your object rather than using @
module.exports = AtomMarkdownLabels =
  # other stuff here

  file_changed_added: (file_path) ->
    fs.readFile file_path, 'utf-8', AtomMarkdownLabels.process_yaml
    console.log 'file changed'

  process_yaml: (err, data) ->
    console.log "process_yaml is called"
```

---

This should solve [your other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40100881/479863) CoffeeScript problem from a few days ago too.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I believe you are right that this is the cause of the issue I was running into previously.